# If every isometry on a Hilbert space is unitary, then $H$ is finite dimensional.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, isometry

Suppose that $H$ is a Hilbert space such that every isometry $T\colon H\to H$ is also unitary. In other words, $T^{*}T=I\implies TT^{*}=I$ for all $T\in B(H)$. Then why is $H$ necessarily finite dimensional?

I tried to work with the innerproduct and the definition of the adjoint, but I don't see how the "algebraic" assumption translates into a statement about the dimension of $H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if $H$ is infinite-dimensional, you can find a countably infinite orthonormal set $e_1, e_2, \ldots$ Hence we can define an isometry $T$ such that $T(e_i) = T(e_{i+1})$ and $T(x) = x$ for any $x$ that is orthogonal to each $e_i$. $T$ is not surjective, so there is no $S$ such that $TS = I$.

(Note that $H$ will contain elements that are not orthogonal to each $e_i$ but are not in the linear span of the $e_i$. These elements comprise the intersection of all complete subspaces that include each $e_i$. Any such element can be written as $u = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} t_ie_i$, so that we must define $T(u) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} t_ie_{i+1}$.)

Comment: Very shifty answer.

Comment: @RobArthan Very clever! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @copper.hat: is "shifty" good or bad? $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: @RobArthan I have one question. I see that $T$ restricted to the closed linear span of $\{e_{n}\}_{n}$ is isometric and similarly the restriction to the complement, but how do I conclude that $T$ is isometric on all of $H$?

Comment: $H$ splits as the direct sum $E \oplus X$ where $E$ is the intersection of all complete subspaces containing the $e_i$ and $X$ is the orthogonal complement of $E$ (and comprises the $x$ that are orthogonal to each $e_i$). Given $u, v \in H$, write $u = e  + x$ and $v = f + y$, where $e, f \in E$ and $x, y\in X$ and check that $\langle e + x, f + y \rangle = \langle T(e + x), T(f + y)\rangle$.

Comment: I've tried to clarify the answer to make it clearer how $T$ is defined. I hope that helps.

Comment: @copper.hat: after several days, I now think I have got the joke. $\ddot{\smile}$.